# Automatically scaled opacity for multi-layered images

Tags: gimp, transparency

I have several set of images with a fixed background and an object moving in the foreground. I'd like to get an idea of the motion of the object by superimposing images with scaled opacity.

If I load a single bunch of `N` images into GIMP as `N` distinct layers, is there a way to *automatically* set the opacity of all the layers to get a scale effect from the first with `P1%` (e.g. 0% opacity) to the last with `P2%` (e.g. 100% opacity)?

Comment: Hi alextoind, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Did you Google around for scripts? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is feasible from the Python Console window. 
Opacity is a layer property, so it is possible to set it with a simple attribution.

Go to `filters->Python Fu->Console`  - there you can type Python expressions. The first one you want is to get a reference to your image - for example:
`img = gimp.image_list()[0]` (press `enter`afterwards)  will get you a reference to the latest (rightmost tab) open image in GIMP. (increase the numbers from 0 inside the brackets to get to the other images)

The layers are available as a Python list when you type img.layers, and the opacity varies from 0.0 to 100.0  - so, the first thing to do is to calculate how much you want to increase the opacity from one layer to the next - that number is:
`opacity_step = 100.0 / (len(img.layers) - 1)` 
(just type the variable names, like `img` and `opacity_step` by themselves and press enter to check their values).
Now, just pick a starting opacity - ex. `current_opacity = 0.0` and then iterate over all layers with a  `for` command, setting the opacity. So, putting everything together, you should type:

```
img = gimp.image_list()[0]
opacity_step = 100.0 / (len(img.layers) - 1)
current_opacity = 0.0
for layer in reversed(img.layers):
    layer.opacity = current_opacity
    current_opacity += opacity_step
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even know about the Python console inside GIMP (:shy:), and this changes everything. Many thanks!

Comment: There is a little mistake: it should be `opacity_step = 100.0 / (len(img.layers) - 1)` to cover the whole range, but it works like a charm!

Comment: Oh well...off by one errors are one of those two things that never go away. Fixed in the example.

Comment: Shouldn't it check for > 2 layers (and do nothing for <= 2 layers), and take the opacity of the upper and lowermost layers into account as well? At least that's how I read the question, albeit the changes required for this are trivial.

Comment: This answer is not a complete plug-in code, it is rather a guide for for the O.P. to type interactively at the interactive prompt. If it where a proper plug-in, then some more lines checking for corner cases, and even more options would be easy to add.